# Review paper on gene expression regulatory mechanisms

Tags: gene-regulation, review

I'm a junior grad student in bioinformatics with CS background. I am involved in a project around discovering gene regulatory networks in some data, which got me curious about the gene expression regulatory mechanisms in eukaryotes. I found this page on Nature, which looks super helpful:
https://www.nature.com/collections/pfdsgqgzck

But it does have 27 review papers listed there. Are there any review papers you could suggest that sums up/introduces different regulatory mechanisms and regulatory factors (CTCF, chromatin accessibility, TFs, enhancers, promoters, lncRNAs etc) in a more global overview?

Thanks!

Comment: That page looks to be a promotional effort for their review articles, organized by recency and selected by some keyword like 'regulation'.